# Angular SSL cert and key -- Ng Serve root directory

Tags: node.js, angular, express, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to set a SSL an ssl-key and cert file on ng serve. ex:

```
ng serve --ssl true --ssl-key './assets/somekey.key' --ssl-cert './assets/somecert.cert'
```

However, running this code, the Angular CLI generated its own key and certificate.
I can not find where it did so, searching online, it's supposed to create it in an 'SSL' folder somewhere, but this folder is nowhere to be found in my project directory.

*I want to use a specific custom key and cert, as I want to try to use the same cert and key for my API. Since I am using a self-signed certificate, I'm hoping this will allow me to trust the front-end angular certificate, and by doing so, trust the back-end certificate as well, as it's the same. I'm not sure if this is possible.*

So my questions here:

> - Where is the default SSL folder where angular generates its key and cert files?
> - What is the root directory ng uses if we add paths to 'ng serve' scripts?
> - Can we use the same certificate for the front - and backend to avoid needing to trust them both? (don't know how to trust back-end since
>     I'm only receiving json so I don't even get a warning to trust,
>     http-requests just fail)

Comment: why don't you just use not encrypted `http` for the frontend?

Comment: Because I want to use the front-end to show to the user that they need to trust the certificate. That way at least they get a meaningful error. I'm hoping that when they trust that certificate (and I'm using the same key and cert files on the back-end), the back-end will also be trusted, and not just silently fail.

Comment: `ng serve` is supposed to be used only during development. For production environments you should upload the results of `ng build` and have a server  such as nginx with certificates from a trusted CA serve the files and proxy your API.
Apart from that, you wouldn't be able to "trust both certificates", as browsers base that off of the host. And since you're running your frontend and API separately, they have to be running on different hosts.

Answer (score 0):

My Apache2 webserver has already a server certificate installed for server 'hp-probook'.

My Angular DEVELOPMENT server will use those certificates as well.

Test it from the shell:

ng serve --ssl 1 --ssl-cert /etc/ssl/private/hp-probook.key.pem --ssl-key /etc/ssl/private/hp-probook.key.pem --host hp-probook

If it works, then you can supply the cerficate info in package.json as well:

Then modify the scripts.code entry in package.json file:

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "code": "ng serve --ssl 1 --ssl-cert /etc/ssl/private/hp-probook.key.pem --ssl-key /etc/ssl/private/hp-probook.key.pem",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Start it:

ng serve --host hp-probook --open